# how to install database with Windows Forms application?

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms, sql-server-2012

I am starting with a new Windows Form Application project in C# and I would be using database in it. I already have SQL Server 2012 installed on my PC.

What type of database should I use and how should I use it so that I can also include it in my setup file and that database can be used in other PCs without installing SQL Server.

Please guide accordingly as I am new to this.

Comment: If your app uses Sql Server you need Sql Server installed unless you have programmed your app to be database independent. Not an easy task.

Comment: i haven't started the app yet. As database is an important requirement of my application, I need a right direction to follow. please help

Comment: Then I suggest to use Sql Server Compact (or SQLite) These databases are simple to deploy and all the libraries needed to work with them could be distributed by your deployment script. Given the familiarity with Sql Server I would choose Sql Server Compact

Comment: thank you steve. I'll try this with my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options that come to mind:

1. [Attach a database file](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-10-0-oledb-provider/attach-a-database-file-located-in-the-data-directory-on-connect-to-a-local-sql-server-express-instance/) to a local SQL Server instance. This will only work when SQL Server is actually installed on the local host.
2. Develop against SQL Server Compact (CE) instead of SQL Server. SQL CE is somewhat like SQLite (if you know it), i.e. your application only includes a database file, the "server" is <strike>part of the .NET Framework.</strike> a single assembly that you can deploy along with your other application binaries. It's less feature-complete though than a full installation of SQL Server.

Comment: SQL Compact and SQLite requires libraries to be distributed. They are not part of the NET Framework

Comment: i'll try with 2nd option. thanks for help

Comment: @Steve: You're right, I didn't remember that one correctly. Fixed. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 0):

Will the DB need to be shared for mmultiple users or is it stand-alone where each user can have his/her own db?  If its multi-user then Sql Server needs to be installed on a server.  If its really a stand alone Db then you can distribute a version of Sql Server with the app.  Unless you are using advanced Sql Server features you could use one of the lighter weight Sql Server variations like Sql Server Express or Sql CE that can be distributed freely.

As far as setting up the tables, you have a couple options.  One is to have a set of Sql scripts that can be run during your set up.  If you are using Entity Framework, then you could use the Code First approach which would generate the DB automatically.

Comment: thank you smith for your help. the DB is stand-alone for each user and does not need to be shared with anyone over any network. i want that the target machine should not require any additional installations or internet connection to run my application. mine is a very simple windows form application.